# How to model non-linear demand function?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, forecasting

I am trying to build a dynamic pricing algorithm on intermittent data (a lot of zeros between non-zero values). I have on average 100 non-zero data points for each product. However, it seems to be quite difficult to predict the right price due to various reasons (non-regular demand, intermittent data, noises etc) so for the first step, I am trying to forecast the demand of each product using [MAPA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MAPA/index.html) from  Nikolaos Kourentzes. I hope to use this demand forecast and price-demand relation to predict the optimal price.

However, in practice these price-demand relationships tend to be non-linear so I was wondering if anyone here could guide me to papers/resources that I can follow to train non-linear model(s) on the price-demand relationship with intermittent demand data. Ideally, the trained model should be optimizable for price.

[Update 23/03/2019 : Added images/tables for elaborating Dynamic pricing]

The input is a intermittent sales data that looks something like the example shown below for most products.
[image: Sales data]
(Intermittent demand image courtesy [to](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yun_Kim13))

Using Dynamic pricing, I would like to model the price-demand relation like the one shown below. Important : Linear demand are not realistic and in my case, the demand for my case **non-linear**.
[image: Linear Demand]

(Linear demand image  [from](https://insightr.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/pricing-optimization-how-to-find-the-price-that-maximizes-your-profit/))

In the end, I hope to create a model that can tell me what the optimal price is given a certain demand.

[image: Optimal price]

(Optimal demand image [from](https://insightr.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/pricing-optimization-how-to-find-the-price-that-maximizes-your-profit/)

Comment: Have you tried RNN (LSTM or GRU) models ? These should be able to capture non-linear relationships in time series.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. Could you give an example what you data looks like and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ShamitVerma I think any RNN models would be an overkill because I do not have much data. Maybe it would have been smarter for mention it in the question.

Comment: @MachineLearner I will edit my question to include a general example

Comment: How much data is availalbe for training ?

Comment: I cannot tell you the exact number as it is sales data which is dynamic in nature. However,  there are on average 100 non-zero data points per product.